# NoReverseMatch in GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am using GAE version 1.7.0 and the "django_example" app downloaded from Google's sample apps.  If I run this app using `dev_appserver.py`, it works fine.

Then I modified the app to use Django 1.2 (by default it uses 0.96). I login, then click "Create new gift", then I get:

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'views.edit' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

The debug screen shows the offending line (in `gift.html`) as

```
<form action="<span class="specific">{%url views.edit gift.key.id%}</span>" method="post">
```

With the "Create new gift" button, `gift.key.id` equals `None`. I also tried using Django 1.3 and got a similar error.

Can someone tell me why it works for 0.96, but not for 1.2 or 1.3?

Update:

I have not modified 'urls.py' from the original example for any of these tests. This file contains:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns(
  '',
  (r'^$', 'views.index'),
  (r'^new$', 'views.new'),
  (r'^edit/(\d+)$', 'views.edit'),
  )
```

Comment: Please provide your urls configuration.

Comment: My urls.py has been added @Secator